# How can I synchronize account between geth servers?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have setup geth in 2 servers as a private testing Etheruem environment.

In the 1st server, I have created accounts.
For the 2nd server, I would like to build as a node to attach the 1st server.
After I have setup and mount the 2nd server, 2 server can synchronize the number of block immediately.

However, the accounts in the 1st server cannot be found in the 2nd server.
Is there a way to synchronize accounts between nodes?

If no, it implied that each account can be access from a single server only even there are multiple nodes/server for the single private Ethereum network.

Appreciate if there is any idea.

Comment: Geth will not synchronized accounts, you have to synchronized them on your own.

Comment: Hi Ismael, thank you for your idea. I have tried to search Internet but I cannot find a clear answer about the synchronization of accounts between nodes. I am sorry to ask this question. Highly appreciate if you may have information on account synchronization between ethereum nodes. thank you very much.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have used --kyestore option to share keystore detail between two nodes. whenever I create an account from node1, it does not reflect into node2.
but if i restart both node, the newly added account is getting reflected in both nodes. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

By default, `geth` stores accounts as a plain files in `keystore` directory inside its data directory specified by `--datadir` command line option.  You may copy these files between `geth` instances and `geth` will catch them up immediately without restart.

If you didn't specify `--datadir`, then `geth` uses default location:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%\Ethereum
```

Also, if you have network directory shared between servers taht run your `geth` instances, you may put account files there and pass path to them to `geth` via `--keystore` command-line option.

See `geth` [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) and [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to synchronize accounts.
Just share key store between both geth servers using --keystore command line option.